# how do i select specific items from a array to display in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am new in iOS programming, and i an writing my first app. I have a NSMutableArray with items in it.These objects has title, id etc. and favorite attribute. The favorite attribute is a bool and tells if the item is added to favorites by the user. Now to my question: in UITableView, i only want all the items with favorite = YES to be displayed in the 'table'. How do i do that ? Do i have to loop through the array and save these items in a new array before i come to the method cellForRowAtIndexPath ? Like in viewDidLoad maybe? Because i tried to set a condition in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but then there was only a bunch of empty cells displayed + my one favorite item. Help Pleese !

Answer (score 3):

I would loop with a for-in statement through the array and make a new *favoriteArray with all the items in it, that you want displayed in the tableView.
So something like:

```
 NSMutableArray *favoriteArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (Item *item in self.mutableArray) {
    if (item.favorite) {
        [favoriteArray addObject:item];
    }
}
```